# Error Process Olap Cube

Tags: sql-server, olap

When I start to process Olap cube I have an error:

**File system error:** The following error occurred while opening file **F:...\554.fact.data**

Next time I run file changes to **554.fact.data,555.fact.data**

How can I fix this error?

Screenshot of run first time.
[image: Run first time]

Screenshot of run second time.

[image: Run second time]

Comment: Include the rest of the error message(s).   Your post only contains an insignificant piece of the error message.

Comment: I added 2 screenshot.

Comment: Looks like your are using 2008 SSAS and assuming MSS 2005 R2.  This article may pertain to your issue https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2276495  Hope this helps!

Comment: Try Method 1, Method 2. Error is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add full control user access to folder by SSASuser - 
"**server-name\sqlserverMSASUser$server-name$MSSQLSERVER**"